# How to check the occurence of each words in the textfile and display the number of times C++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ issue. Currently i have a text file that store the following data. I wish to do a simple program where it will read the data and print out the most frequent display of item and the quantity of it.

I do not wish to set an array of fixed number of words to search through the file as the item entered into the text file is not predetermined

Below are the structure of the data in the text file

The fourth value is the quantity and the second value is the item name

Text File:

```
1|Bag|2|3|6|20Apr2015
2|Fruit|2.3|5|11.5|20Aug2015
4|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Jun2015
5|File|0.9|5|4.5|20Jul2015
6|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Nov2015
7|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20May2015
8|Bag|0.9|5|4.5|20Jan2015
9|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Feb2015
10|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Jan2015
11|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Dec2015
12|File|0.9|5|4.5|20Oct2015
13|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Sep2015
14|Water|0.9|5|4.5|20Sep2015
```

Desired Output:

The most frequent item is Water and 40 are sold

The least frequent item is Fruit and 5 are sold

Here is my current coding

```
    void computeItem()
    {


        string itemid;
        float totalprice;
        string item[4] ={"Water","Bag","Fruit","File"}; 
        int itemqty[4]={};

        int founditem;
        int foundyear;
        string year;
        string found;

        cout<<endl;


            for(int i = 0; i < MAX- 1; i++)
            {
                if(transactionpile[i].itemid !="")
                {
                    for(int k=0; k<4;k++)
                    {   

                            founditem = transactionpile[i].itemdesc.find(item[k]);
                            if(foundmonth<transactionpile[i].itemdesc.length())
                            {
                                //Add the totalprice of each found records to totalsalesmonth[k]
                                itemqty[k] += transactionpile[i].quantity;

                            }

                    }


                    }

                }


        }



        //Print out the output
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {

            cout << "            " << item[i] << "            " <<  << itemqty[i] <<endl;


        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried to search a set of words predefined in an array to loop through the text file and captured the quantity, but i am not able to compare the quantity for the diff item, but this is not what i want. So hope that someone can give me some enlightment in doing this. Thanks alot

Comment: Post the code that you've tried

Comment: I have added the current code that i have now on my post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, while looping through the file, you could dynamically grow a `std::vector` of items? So, each time you run across an item, check to see if it's already in the vector and, if it isn't, push it onto the end. Aside from that, just treat the vector like the array you're using now (I presume . . . I can't really tell what you're doing now).